# Ground state energy of Bose Einstein gas

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity, ground-state

I am wondering why BE gas ground state contribute no energy.if so, then dose it mean that if we drive the Bose gas to absolute zero,then it doesn't own any energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that all atoms are in the ground state, then since potential energy is defined up to a constant you can say ground state has zero energy

Comment: What is interesting is to compare to fermions : 2 fermions cannot be in the same state, so if you cool down a fermion gas you will fill states from the ground one to the Nth one (if you have N atoms)